# Start animation in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, animation, kotlin, floating-action-button

I'm trying to implement some animations in my Floating Action Button. These are the one I've inside my animation directory:

```
var fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fab_open);
var fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.fab_close);
var rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate_forward);
var rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate_backward);
```

I set up that, on button click, these animation must start. I linked them to the floating button on this way:

```
private fun animateFAB() {
    fab!!.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
    fab!!.startAnimation(fab_close);
}
```

The problem is that I get this error on the declaration of the animations:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You can't use `context` until the Activity or Fragment has been created. Make the properties `lateinit` and assign them in `onCreate()` (or `onCreateView()`).

Comment: I declared the four variable as **var fab_open = null** and I put, inside the onCreateView,  **fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fab_open);**, but I gives me the error: Required: Nothing? - Found: Animation!

Comment: You need to declare their types. Don’t make properties nullable if you don’t have to. The declaration should look like this: `lateinit var fab_open: Animation`